# What is the difference between Windows Mobile 6 Professional and Standard SDKs

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

What are the differences between Windows Mobile 6 Professional and Standard SDKs?

Comment: Sorry, didnt see the tags. Differences explained here. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=06111a3a-a651-4745-88ef-3d48091a390b Next time please do a simple google search before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i am not sure, but according to me the Windows professional and Standard SDK both the used for the Software development Kit, but While using Windows professional you also need to include some DLL as it contains the new version and have the vast library.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I work on legacy devices I always end up having to Google this, and usually end up here.

In summary:

**Windows Mobile 6 Classic** are the traditional PDAs (and what used to be called Pocket PC devices).
They have no phone functionality

**Windows Mobile 6 Professional** devices are phones with touchscreens.
WM6 Professional runs the same software as WM6 Classic

**Windows Mobile 6 Standard** devices are phones *without* touchscreens.
Because WM6 Standard devices have no touchscreen they cannot run software designed for either WM6 Classic or WM6 Professional

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the dead link

Answer (score 2):

Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK Refresh does not contain the Windows Mobile Standard SDK Refresh and you will need to download both to target both platforms.

Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK Refresh contains Windows Mobile 6 Professional emulator images and one Windows Mobile 6 Classic emulator image.